# Managing a get people ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax request that prints the people data onto the page. The people data is collated from a back end database. There is a search form on the page that include location, sector, service and job title.

Here is my javascript:

```
//var keyPeople = '';
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['keyPeople'])) { ?>
    var keyPeople = <?php echo $_REQUEST['keyPeople']; ?>;
<?php } else { ?>
    var keyPeople = '';
<?php } ?>

<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['keySector'])) { ?>
    var keySector = '<?php echo urldecode($_REQUEST['keySector']); ?>';
<?php } else { ?>
    var keySector = '';
<?php } ?>

<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['keyService'])) { ?>
    var keyService = '<?php echo urldecode($_REQUEST['keyService']); ?>';
<?php } else { ?>
    var keyService = '';
<?php } ?>

var loaderHTML = '<div class="ajax-loader" style="padding: 20px; text-align: center"><img src="' + CCM_IMAGE_PATH + '/throbber_white_32.gif"></div>';

$('.load-more').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('nextpage') != 'eor' || $(this).data('nextpage') != 'nr') {
        getPeople($(this).data('nextpage'));
    }
});

function getPeople(pageNumber) {
        $('.load-more').before(loaderHTML);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $loadUrl; ?>',
            cache: false,
            data: {'parent_id': '<?php echo $parentID; ?>', 'page': pageNumber, 'name': $('#people-name').val(), 'location': $('#office-location .selecter-selected').text(), 'sectors': $('#sectors .selecter-selected').text(), 'service': $('#services .selecter-selected').text(), 'jobtitle': $('#jobtitle .selecter-selected').text(), 'keyPeople': keyPeople, 'keySector': keySector, 'keyService': keyService},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.ajax-loader').fadeOut(function() {
                    //console.log(data);
                    var pageData = '';
                    var searchParams = new Array();

                    if(data.locationParam != null) {
                        searchParams.push(data.locationParam);
                    }
                    if(data.sectorParam != null) {
                        searchParams.push(data.sectorParam);
                    }
                    if(data.serviceParam != null) {
                        searchParams.push(data.serviceParam);
                    }

                    if (typeof searchParams !== 'undefined' && searchParams.length > 0) {
                        pageData += '<h2>Our People: ';
                        pageData += searchParams.join(', ');
                        pageData += '</h2>';
                    }

                    if(data.noResults == 'nor') {
                        pageData += '<h3 class="no-results">Sorry, no results found</h3>';
                    } else {
                        $.each(data.pages, function(k, v) {

                            pageData += '<div class="grid person-list-item">';
                            pageData += '<div class="col col-3 person-thumbnail">';
                            if(v.image != null) {
                                pageData += '<a href="'+v.url+'"><img src="'+v.image+'" alt="'+v.title+'"></a>';
                            }
                            pageData += '</div>';

                            pageData += '<div class="col col-9 person-info">';
                            pageData += '<h3><a href="'+v.url+'">'+v.title+'</a></h3>';
                            if(v.jobtitle != null) {
                                pageData += '<p class="lead-partner"><strong>'+v.jobtitle.value+'</strong></p>';
                            }
                            pageData += '<p>';
                            if(v.location != null) {
                            pageData += '<strong>Location:</strong> '+v.location.value+'<br>';
                            }
                            if(v.tel != false) {
                                pageData += '<strong>Tel:</strong> '+v.tel+'<br>';
                            }
                            if(v.mobile != false) {
                                pageData += '<strong>Mobile:</strong> '+v.mobile+'<br>';
                            }
                            if(v.email != false) {
                                pageData += '<strong>Email: <a href="mailto:'+v.email+'">'+v.email+'</a></strong>';
                            }
                            pageData += '</p>';
                            pageData += '<a href="'+v.url+'" class="button button-green">Read More</a>';
                            if(v.linkedIn != false) {
                                pageData += '<a href="'+v.linkedIn+'" class="button button-blue">LinkedIn Profile</a>';
                            }
                            pageData += '</div></div>';

                        });

                    }

                    if (pageNumber == 1) {
                        $('#page-list').empty();
                    }

                    $('#page-list').append(pageData);

                    if (data.nextPage == 'eor') {
                        $('.load-more').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('.load-more').html('Load more people').data('nextpage', data.nextPage).fadeIn();
                    }

                    if(data.noResults == 'nor') {
                        $('.load-more').hide();
                    }

                    $('.ajax-loader').remove();
                });
            }
        });

}
getPeople(1);

$("#people-search-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#page-list').empty();
    getPeople(1);
});
```

Ok sorry if its a bit overwhelming, here is what this does. On page load it displays all the first 10 people in the database table. On click (load more) it displays a further 10, thus firing the ajax call again. Each person is taken from a json array.

It's also possible to search for multiple certain params e.g. location, sector etc. After the search has been triggered it displays the search params as a title:

```
pageData += '<h2>Our People: ';
pageData += searchParams.join(', ');
pageData += '</h2>';
```

Understandably this gets appended to the page after every click of the (load more) button. I only want this to be appended once at the top the page and/or changed if the search params change? Any ideas on what I need to do to achieve this? I kinda know I need a new function as at it stands the function getPeople gets called after every load more click.

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense!!

Comment: Maybe give that `h2` element an id, and use that to check whether or not it already exists in the document _before_ appending it …?

Comment: Its getting appended because it's part of the function call. I need to take the h2 part of the function out into its own function i think? Trouble is I need to amend the h2 every time the user filters by another value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are calling

```
$('#page-list').append(pageData);
```

use

```
$('#page-list').html(pageData);
```

to replace the current html with this html

If you want to append then define the h2 tag with an id, outside of the pageData html (so it doesn't get appended each time). e.g.:

```
<h2 id='ourPeople'></h2>
```

Then instead of

```
pageData += '<h2>Our People: ';
pageData += searchParams.join(', ');
pageData += '</h2>';
```

define a new var at the top of your $('.ajax-loader').fadeOut(function() {
like:

```
var ourPeopleText = '';
```

Change the contents of this statement: if (typeof searchParams !== 'undefined' && searchParams.length > 0) { to

```
ourPeopleText += 'Our People: ';
ourPeopleText += searchParams.join(', ');
```

and then at the bottom where you call

```
$('#page-list').append(pageData);
```

also call

```
$('#ourPeople').html(ourPeopleText);
```

Comment: The next 10 results are appended to the existing 10 so .append() is needed here.

Comment: Ah. I thought you wanted to replace with the next 10. Will adjust my response

Comment: I guess i'll need to replace the h2 on every ajax call though with the different search params.

Comment: You don't need to replace the h2 tag - just the html contents of the tag